# Javascript classes, singleton and how to init multiple object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand how to manage object and classes in Javascript.
My frontend ha several elements: some element, like the menu, is unique, so I have to init only one time, but I have some object where I can have multiple instance on the pages, like for example a gallery.

Now for the menu I have

```
export class Menu {
  init() {
  ...
  }
}

export default new Menu();
```

And then

```
import MenuSingleTon, { Menu } from './menus';

const menu = new Menu();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  menu.init();
})
```

For my galleries I'm using something similar

```
export class Gallery {

  constructor() {
  ....
  }

  init() {
   $('gallery').each((i, el) => 
    new gallery($(el)));
  }
}

export default new Gallery();
```

But I think this approach is wrong. I'm not sure.

Comment: The simplest Singleton in JavaScript is an object.

Comment: Yes, like in ruby. But is the right way to use a singleton to manage multiple elements?

Comment: `const menu = new Menu();` is absolutely fine. `export default new Menu();` is not.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain me why?

Comment: @RobertoPezzali Not the module that provides the class should decide that your app uses a singleton. If it did (which is sometimes the case), then it shouldn't use a `class`, but just create an object, like Jonas suggested.

Comment: So Is what I’m asking. I have to export the class without new?